# Using timer object in python to call a function after certain invertal

Tags: python, multithreading

I have  used the following technique to call a function after  certain interval. My problem is that it is being called twice at an interval of 5 seconds. That is after every 5 seconds this function is being called twice. How to resolve this? This code is a part of a class.

```
self.t=Timer(5,self.checkTimeOut)
   self.t.start()
def checkTimeOut(self):
     print("Game Over")
     Timer(5,self.checkTimeOut).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a timer I wrote a while ago. Try it out with this. For me it works perfectly!

```
def CountDown(t):
while t:
    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
    #print timeformat
    #timeformat = '\r{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
    #sys.stdout.write(timeformat)
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
```

Call it like this:

```
def main():
    minutes = 1
    cntTime = minutes * 60
    while(True):
        CountDown(cntTime)
        YourFunction()
```